# Centering rotated text in a multirow cell in a table with images

Tags: tables, multirow, rotating

the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{graphbox} %loads graphicx package
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} 
    & ro1 1 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\ 
    & row 2 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.1]{example-image} & text\\
    & row 3 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.4]{example-image} & text\\ 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} 
    & row 1 & without example-image & text\\ 
    & row 2 & without example-image & text\\
    & row 3 & without example-image & text\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

gives me the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to center the rotated text?

Comment: you are close -- all you need to do is change the following code --`\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}}` the multirow option for number of lines can be arbitrary and even decimal for fine tuning of the centering -- in the second case change the code to `\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Text}} `  --you can read the multirow and makecell documentation for even more options at -- http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf and at http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583790/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %loads graphicx package
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        \multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Text}} 
        & ro1 1 & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\ 
        & row 2 & \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image} & text\\
        & row 3 & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image} & text\\ 
    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{Text}} 
        & row 1 & \makecell[l]{without example-image  \\ without example-image \\ without example-image}& text\\ 
        & row 2 & \makecell[l]{without example-image  \\ without example-image \\ without example-image}& text\\
        & row 3 & \makecell[l]{without example-image  \\ without example-image \\ without example-image} & text\\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I was able to get the desired result after tinkering with the multirow option for the number of lines (as you have suggested). Since the NiceTabular command don't work on my system (unfortunately) your solution is the one I will use.

Answer (score 2):

Have a nice welcome here! :)

Some weeks ago, I had a very similar problem, according to this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579879/tabularx-center-a-vertical-table-heading-rotated-multicolumn). A decent solution is to use a `NiceTabular` from the `nicematrix` package by  F. Patigny (see [documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf)). That provides some block logic, thus you don't need `multirow` and `makecell` anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{graphbox} %loads graphicx package

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}
  \Block{*-1}{\rotate{Text}}
  & row 1 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\ 
  & row 2 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.1]{example-image} & text\\
  & row 3 & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.4]{example-image} & text\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}
  \Block{*-1}{\rotate{Text}}
  & row 1 & without example-image & text\\ 
  & row 2 & without example-image & text\\
  & row 3 & without example-image & text\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

(You probably have to compile the document twice.)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your output is exactly what i asked for. Unfortunately my editor couldn’t compile the code due to an issue with the NiceTabular Environment i wasn’t able resolve ("undefinded Environment"). I don’t know how to troubleshoot package issues as I never see them, so it’s possible your code doesn’t work just on my system.

Comment: @rogr: You have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Yes, you were right. I use LaTeX primarily Ubuntu and updating the TeX packages is a whole nother issue for itself. After switching to Windows I updated all the installed TeX packages via MikTeX Console and the code provided by Max16hr worked. Thank you all.